# .htaccess redirect issue with multiple .htaccess file

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I am using .htaccess file like below for redirect www to non www on my public_html directory

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%1/$1 [R=301,L]
```

its working fine and redirect like below

```
    www.example.com
to
    https://example.com
```

Now in my sub directory called latest, I have another .htaccess file like below

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/\.]+)/?$ index.php?page=$1 [L]
```

which is making my url clean like below

```
www.example.com/latest/index.php?page=1
to
www.example.com/latest/1
```

but even I have .htaccess file in home directory which is making www to non www, my this directory does not redirect www to non www.

I want redirect

```
www.example.com/latest/1
to 
https://example.com/latest/1
```

I am sure .htaccess file in my directory is causing issue but I do not know how to resolve it. Let me know if anyone here can help me for the same.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is, `mod_rewrite` is not inherited (at least by default). If you have a rewrite rule in the "default" directory .. You're going to have to include that rule in all subsequent directories "below" that.   I have never seen (or heard of) a setting for allowing `mod_rewrite` to allow inheritance from parent `.htaccess` files.  In general, this is just accepted as "the way it is".

**UPDATE**

[THIS QUESTION](https://serverfault.com/questions/958147/is-it-possible-to-override-an-htaccess-directive-after-it-has-been-set) In Server Fault explains this as well.  The `mod_rewrite` rules from the previous `htaccess` files don't even get processed.

**COMBINE THE 2 in the SUB DIRECTORIES**

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%1/$1 [R=301,L]

# add this only to sub directories
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/\.]+)/?$ index.php?page=$1 [L]
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I am not redirect expert. can you help me for modify my latest directory .htaccess file for the same? Thanks